Redefinition of timeval
I'm developing a pintools that makes use of the winsock2 lib. I'm working on Windows, so to perform the compilation via make command I installed cygwin.
When compiling I get the following error:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um\winsock2.h(180,8): error: redefinition of 'timeval'
  180 | struct timeval {
      |        ^
../../../extras/crt/include/kernel/uapi\linux/time.h(31,8): note: previous definition is here
   31 | struct timeval {
      |        ^
1 error generated.

I tried to undef the timeval struct, but with no results.

Can you find out where time.h is included? I suppose it is included indirectly by some other include file. Perhaps, you can avoid this inclusion and define missing prototypes or constants locally.

#include 
#include 
#include 
#include <winsock2.h>
#include "pin.H"
These are my inclusion. Probably it is used in pin.H, but i cannot avoid its inclusion

It must be something included prior to winsock2.h. Sometimes, you can influence the inclusion by defining macros which control if certain files are actually included.

I added the macro #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN, with no results

Include the build process as well (commands, variables, ...). Based on the output (I see both paths from VStudio and Cygwin's build tools), the way you're building your code is wrong. Pick one build system and stick with it.
